# AWS DMS - PostgreSQL invalid input value for enum and daterange

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I'm performing a logical replication from our PostgreSQL server to AWS RDS, using the database migration tool (DMS). Most tables were migrated successfully, but I'm having troubles with a couple of the tables.

When I run the task to load the table, I get this error on the logs of RDS:

```
ERROR:  invalid input value for enum property_type: ""
CONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $17 = ''
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "public"."loans"("id","account_id","loan_number","created_at","updated_at","folio","mers_min","mers_status","mers_status_date","application_number","servicer","servicer_loan_number","status","primary_borrower_last_name","primary_borrower_first_name","property_number_of_units","property_type","property_address_line1","property_address_line2","property_city","property_state","property_zip","property_county_code","property_country_code","property_census_tract_code","property_parcel_id","mortgage_type","qm_loan","purpose","ltv","amortization_type","amount","interest_rate","term","lien_priority","application_date","approval_date","rejected_date","closing_date","funding_date","purchase_date","source","officer","processor","underwriter","appraiser","property_usage","fha_case_number","var_payload","approval_type","approval_message","housing_expense_ratio","total_debt_expense_ratio","subordinate_financing_amount","combined_ltv","property_appraised_value","property_purchase_price","property_appraised_date","property_year_built","credit_score","au_type","au_recommendation","lender_product","heloc_indicator","reverse_indicator","property_pud_indicator","closer","additional_financing_amount","rejected_reason","mortgage_insurance_certificate_number","mortgage_insurance_coverage_amount","mortgage_insurance_premium","day_one_certainty","first_payment_date","maturity_date","principal_and_interest_payment_amount","is_portfolio","financing_concessions_amount","sales_concessions_amount","transaction_costs_amount","is_investment_quality","application_received_date","lender_program","refinance_cash_out_type") values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33,$34,$35,$36,$37,$38,$39,$40,$41,$42,$43,$44,$45,$46,$47,$48,$49,$50,$51,$52,$53,$54,$55,$56,$57,$58,$59,$60,$61,$62,$63,$64,$65,$66,$67,$68,$69,$70,$71,$72,$73,$74,$75,$76,$77,$78,$79,$80,$81,$82,$83,$84)
```

The type of column `property_type` is a nullable `enum` that takes as values `Condominium`, `Cooperative`, `ManufacturedHome`, `SingleFamily`, `Townhouse` and `TwoToFourFamily`.

I'm experiencing a similar issue with another table from the same database, where I get:

```
ERROR:  malformed range literal: ""
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis or bracket.
CONTEXT:  unnamed portal parameter $3 = ''
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "public"."selections_sampling_data"("id","sow_id","period","loan_number","field_data","selected_on","substituted_on","substitution_for_id","received_for_review_on","created_at","updated_at","selected_for","selection_reason","selections_sampling_strategy_id") values ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14)
```

This one doesn't explicitly tell me which column generated the error, but parameter `$3` should correspond with the `period` column, which is a `daterange` type.

In both cases, the DMS task seems to be querying for an empty string as value, which is not allowed by those data types.
I don't know if this is an error with my schema, or how I configured the DMS task.

### [Update]

My task configuration is the following:

```json
{
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": true,
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "EventErrorPolicy": "IGNORE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE"
    },
    "ValidationSettings": {
        "ValidationPartialLobSize": 0,
        "PartitionSize": 10000,
        "RecordFailureDelayLimitInMinutes": 0,
        "SkipLobColumns": false,
        "FailureMaxCount": 10000,
        "HandleCollationDiff": false,
        "ValidationQueryCdcDelaySeconds": 0,
        "ValidationMode": "ROW_LEVEL",
        "TableFailureMaxCount": 1000,
        "RecordFailureDelayInMinutes": 5,
        "MaxKeyColumnSize": 8096,
        "EnableValidation": true,
        "ThreadCount": 5,
        "RecordSuspendDelayInMinutes": 30,
        "ValidationOnly": false
    },
    "TTSettings": {
        "TTS3Settings": null,
        "TTRecordSettings": null,
        "EnableTT": false
    },
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "CommitRate": 1000,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 2,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DO_NOTHING"
    },
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 64,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "LobMaxSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": true,
        "FullLobMode": true,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": false,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0
    },
    "BeforeImageSettings": null,
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "StatusTableEnabled": false,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": false,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": false,
        "ControlSchema": "",
        "FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false
    },
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false,
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "StatementCacheSize": 50,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null
}
```

Comment: Can you share if this is a one time load. i.e. fullload only or replication task. Also when are you facing this error while fulload competes initially and once the replication happens? What is your target table preparation mode?

Comment: It's a replication task. The initial load can complete because these tables can't be copied. The target preparation mode is set to do nothing. I will update the question to add this info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after digging through [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#w284aac23c11c19c29b7c15) and contacting support, I learned that `enum` data types don't migrate using DMS. The task will fail no matter what.

If your database has `enum` columns, you need to find another solution, i.e. [barman](https://pgbarman.org/) and run it on an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution we tested, once your `DMS` is over and shutted down, you are able to `alter table` to change the type of the column. It works.

But be sure you will never need to migrate data from source DB to the destination DB since the `DMS` will fail.

Be aware that we had some other issues with `DMS`: `foreign keys` and second `indexes` are not synchronized (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.General.MissingSecondaryObjs).

If you build these indexes on your own, think that you could need to `analyze` your tables to be sure the requests are optimized.